# Ember.js Switching Static Data to REST Server

Tags: javascript, rest, ember.js

Thanks in advance for the help. I am looking for some direction. Currently I have an ember website that has all the data static in the app.js. I would like to move this to a rest server so I can have the ability to change and add records.

Here is my current [code](http://jsbin.com/rijut/1/edit):

I did manage to get a node rest server up, but was not able to get the ember app to connect correctly.

I have tried making some changes to look at the rest server:

```
App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
 revision: 12,
 adapter: DS.RESTAdapter.create({
 url: 'http://localhost:3000'
 })
});

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
 model: function() {
 return this.store.findAll('themes');
 }
});
```

Made changes like that, but it was never able to connect.

Here is that [code](http://jsbin.com/saroh/1/edit):

Here is what my json looks like

```
[
{
"themes": [
  {
    "title": "decode",
    "price": 0,
    "free": true,
    "description": "description full",
    "columns": 1,
    "popular": true,
    "purchaseLink": "link",
    "demoLink": "link",
    "image": "images/img.jpg",
    "votes": 0
  }
],
"_id": "531f97bb3b229700002919f3"
 }
]
```

I have spent a bunch of time trying to figure out how to do this, but this is new to me. If you have any advice, or know of any sort of tutorial that would show me how to take what I have and put the data into a rest server so I can access that data and make changes, I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there-  Try changing the key from `url` to `host` in the adapter config and use `extend` instead of `create`:

```
App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
    revision: 12,
    adapter: DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
        host: 'http://localhost:3000'
     });
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I made this change and am now getting this "Error while loading route: Error: No model was found for '0'". So it seems like it has connected to the Rest server, but isn't reading the data right. Have you run across that? I am also seeing this in the node logs if that helps: 
[ id: 'themes' ]
findById: NaN
null

Thanks again for the help!

Comment: Yes, your problem now is the format of the data coming from your REST backend.  You can either change your server, or modify the adapter by implementing `extractArray` and/or `extractSingle`.

Comment: Great! Thanks! Getting other errors now, but looks like the rest server is working. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

What version of Ember Data are you using? (And if not the latest, can you upgrade? ED has gotten *way* better in the past few months)

In the current version, 1.0.0-beta.7, Ember Data uses the RESTAdapter by default. Simply by running the ember-data.js file after your ember.js file, you should be all set. From looking at your JSBin, it looks like you're not including ember-data at all. Maybe it's there in your actual code, but just in case... it is not included in ember.js by default, you can download it here http://emberjs.com/builds/#/beta.

Once you've included ember-data, the find-all query is `this.store.find('themes')`. See this general section of the ember docs for how to interact with ember data records http://emberjs.com/guides/models/, and **pretty much ignore Ember stack overflow answers prior to October**. Ember is moving pretty fast, and didn't solidify their API until September, and Ember Data in particular has no guarantees about avoiding breaking changes at the moment.

If for some reason you need to explicitly set up the ApplicationAdapter, the code should be like the following (as you now have in your JSBin)

```
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  host: yourHostGoesHere
});
```

Remove `DS.FixtureAdapter` entirely, otherwise I think you're asking for trouble. Also remove `DS.Store`/`App.Store` since `DS.Store` is created for you automatically, and `App.Store` is no longer a thing.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for the comment! Definitely helped to clear things up!